# ForeignKey to a non PrimaryKey but still unique

Tags: entity-framework

I got 2 classes i want to be able to create a ForeignKey to a field that is not the primarykey of the class

my BeerDispense need to point to my Master with an int with the field called MacAdrInt

This way i make my MacAdrInt field point to the primarykey of my master, but i want it to point to MacAdrInt, is this possible or do i need to make it my primarykey?

```
public class Master
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string MacAdr { get; set; }       
    public long MacAdrInt { get; set; }
    ...      
}


public class BeerDispense
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MacAdrInt")]
    public Master Master { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want it to point to MacAdrInt, is this possible or do i need to make it my primarykey?

In EF Core this is possible using [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys).  In EF6 you need configure MacAdrInt as your Key property.  It does not have to be the *real* primary key, but EF6 only supports one Key per entity.